# ng selected show value from realted table

Tags: angularjs

I want to select the "id" that I have stored and display it in the form, I need to edit the form and I need to start the form, is selected the id that stores when saving with their respective names.

```
    <select class="form-control"
     ng-model="vm.operative_order_id" 
     ng-selected="dataOrder.operative_order_id" <!--The "id" or "operative_order_id" is from a related table -->
     ng-options="orderoperatives.id as orderoperatives.nombre for orderoperatives in dataOperatives"></select>
```

The "dataOrder.operative_order_id" and "orderoperatives.id" have the same value, what I want is to show the name of that value.

if dataOrder.operative_order_id = 2 I need it "selected" in the ng-option

```
<option value="2" selected>name</option>
```

Comment: Please check if ng-options is filled before you select the value in the edit
Please delay the value ie vm.operative_order_id pushing. Push the ng-options once it is completed push the vm.operative_order_id again

Comment: I don't understand . can you explain clearly?

Comment: I have a lot values in ng-opcion orderoperatives.id, but I want this selected  dataOrder.operative_order_id. if dataOrder.operative_order_id = 2 I need it "selected" in the ng-option <option value="2" selected>name</option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need ng-selected

Just try this

```
<select class="form-control"  ng-model="dataOrder.operative_order_id" 
ng-options="orderoperatives.id as orderoperatives.nombre for 
orderoperatives in dataOperatives"></select>
```

---

or try this

```
<select class="form-control"
 ng-model="vm.operative_order_id" 
 ng-selected="dataOrder.operative_order_id" ng-options="orderoperatives.id as orderoperatives.nombre for orderoperatives in dataOperatives"></select>
```

and you should assign the`dataOrder.operative_order_id` to `vm.operative_order_id` in controller, something like

```
$scope.operative_order_id=$scope.dataOrder.operative_order_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<select class="form-control"
     ng-model="vm.operative_order_id" >
<option ng-repeat = "item in orderoperatives " value = "{{item .id}}">{{item .nombre}}}</option>
</select>
```

Can you pls try like this :)

Comment: ng-repeat is worst approach than  using ng-option